# mice multilevel imputation multiple variables

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to do multiple imputation using the mice package in R for multilevel models. i am following the steps listed out in [here](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-mlguidelines.html) and [here](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/multiple-imputation-models-for-multilevel-data.html) to set up my predictor matrix. however, the examples provided only include not more than 7 variables in the dataset for the predictor matrix.
How can I do it when I have many variables in the dataset?

Do I have to repeat this (see below- pred) for every variable that I want to impute? (total of 19 variables, and 4 dummy variables) it seems extremely tedious..

```
#create imputation model for Race_R
pred["Race_R", c("a","SchlPre","c", "Age",
                  "Gender","Race_R", "Ethnicity","EnrDipType",
                  "DemHHInc_Rnum","IQ","ABC_SS","d",
                  "SD","GASEndMnAcad","wj3","a1","a2",
                  "DemHHIncx","DemHHIncy")] <- c(0, -2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
```

Also i tried to run the imputation with

```
imp <- mice(data, pred = pred, meth = impmethod, seed = 919,
            m = 10, print = FALSE)
```

but ended up with a bunch of boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular'), and no imputation data was generated. How can i troubleshoot this? thanks!!

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing your data, a portion of your data, or an example dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Predictor matrices do not have to be created manually. There are two `mice` functions available for this task. The resulting objects can then be modified as required for multilevel imputation.

```r
# load packages
library(mice, quietly = TRUE)
library(ggmice, quietly = TRUE)

# example data
head(boys)
#>      age  hgt   wgt   bmi   hc  gen  phb tv   reg
#> 3  0.035 50.1 3.650 14.54 33.7 <NA> <NA> NA south
#> 4  0.038 53.5 3.370 11.77 35.0 <NA> <NA> NA south
#> 18 0.057 50.0 3.140 12.56 35.2 <NA> <NA> NA south
#> 23 0.060 54.5 4.270 14.37 36.7 <NA> <NA> NA south
#> 28 0.062 57.5 5.030 15.21 37.3 <NA> <NA> NA south
#> 36 0.068 55.5 4.655 15.11 37.0 <NA> <NA> NA south

# create full predictor matrix and visualize
pred <- make.predictorMatrix(boys)
plot_pred(pred)
```

[image]

```r
# better: create pruned predictor matrix and visualize
pred <- quickpred(boys)
plot_pred(pred)
```

[image]

```r
# make region the clustering variable for all imputations
pred[, "reg"] <- -2
plot_pred(pred)
```

[image]

```r
# impute all variables with random effects
pred[pred == 1] <- 2
plot_pred(pred)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>